# Is it possible to put programs on a machine through filezilla?

Tags: server, minecraft, filezilla

I know this isn't exactly a coding based thing and I am sorry for that. My friend has a server that we use to store files and run a minecraft server. I know call me lame and you are hella right I am. We use putty and msm as a console for it, but I want to switch to MCSS (https://www.mcserversoft.com/downloads).

My question is would it be possible to install this program on there through filezilla or is not possible? If it is how do I do it?

Comment: This is not possible with filezilla

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, MC Server Soft is meant to be run in a Windows environment. If your server is Windows (which I doubt it is considering the other tools you mentioned), you are probably going to need to remote desktop into your server to install and setup MCSS.